# using aggregate function with more than two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have two tables, stats and stat_log. The stat log is like this:

`user_id,stat_id,value,registered`

and It logs the value of the stats for the given times. I need every last value from every stat for a given user.

So i want something like this, but with values:
`select stat,max(registered) from stat_log where uid = 1 group by stat;`

```
 stat |    max       
------+------------  
    6 | 2009-10-08  
    1 | 2009-10-08  
    3 | 2009-10-08  
    5 | 2009-10-08  
    7 | 2009-10-08  
    4 | 2009-10-08
```

Instead I've got this:

`select stat,max(registered),value from stat_log where uid = 1  group by stat,value;`

```
 stat |    max     | value   
------+------------+-------  
    4 | 2009-10-08 | 38  
    5 | 2009-10-08 | 118  
    1 | 2009-10-08 | 100  
    1 | 2009-10-07 | 101  
    6 | 2009-10-08 | 68  
    3 | 2009-10-08 | 110    
    7 | 2009-10-08 | 53
```

What's the correct query? This is PostgreSQL 8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    distinct on (stat_id)
    *
FROM
    stat_log
WHERE
    user_id = 1
order by stat_id desc, registered_desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is valid SQL for PostgreSQL, but I think you should be able to use something like this:

```
select * from stat_log
inner join (
    select uid,stat,max(registered) as registered from stat_log group by uid,stat
) as maxrecords on stat_log.stat = maxrecords.stat and
                   stat_log.uid = maxrecords.uid and
                   stat_log.registered = maxrecords.registered
where stat_log.uid = 1
```

The 'inner join' limits the results to the rows that you're interested in that are returned by the inner subquery.

Comment: it's valid, but it returns with other users, both dates, etc.

Comment: whoops.  somehow thought stat was a primary key.  Edited and fixed the query though "distinct on" (something I didn't know existed until I saw the above accepted answer!) seems to be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with some non-standard features in Oracle, but otherwise a subquery or a join is required.  I like this form because it's logical to me, but ideally the database would execute it the same way as the joined version.

```
select stat, registered, value
from stat_log a
where
    id = 1
    and registered = (
        select max(registered)
        from stat_log
        where
            b.id = a.id
            and b.stat = a.stat
        )
```